# Non-problematic circular dependencies warnings shown in Angular 9 console

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency, angular9

In my Angular typescript code, I use a class **Class1** that injects an object of class **Class2** in its constructor parameters, so my class **Class2** is imported at the top of **Class1**.

But this class Class2 has a method *Method2* that must have a parameter of type **Class1**, so I also import **Class1** at the top of **Class2**, to type this parameter, that way I'm sure it triggers an error if the argument isn't of the right type (of the right class to be more precise).

Angular now shows me a "circular dependency" warning but there isn't any circular dependencies INJECTED, only a file inclusion loop.

What is the correct way to solve this kind of problem ?